# Using Bing Maps Quadkeys as Openlayers 3 Tile source

Tags: bing-maps, openlayers-3, quadtree

I have a number of tile sources which utilise Bing Maps' Quadkey system in an old Silverlight application and I would like to use them in a new Openlayers 3 map.

I have found several examples of functions which will convert these sources for Leaflet.js but the syntax is somewhat different for OL3 and reading through the API docs indicates that there is an ol.Tile.coord class but if I understand correctly this is an experimental feature and might require a custom build from the source code.

There is reference to such functionality on the GitHub pages but I don't know if I have to compile a build with this source:
https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/5c5364bbb7e8df76f18242ad665c87ca08a76e76/src/ol/source/bingmapssource.js

Can anyone provide an example of this type of conversion or indeed does anyone know if the latest (3.8.2) version of OL3 supports the quadkey method?

This is the leaflet example:

```
var BingLayer = L.TileLayer.extend({
getTileUrl: function (tilePoint) {
    this._adjustTilePoint(tilePoint);
    return L.Util.template(this._url, {
        s: this._getSubdomain(tilePoint),
        q: this._quadKey(tilePoint.x, tilePoint.y, this._getZoomForUrl())
    });
},
_quadKey: function (x, y, z) {
    var quadKey = [];
    for (var i = z; i > 0; i--) {
        var digit = '0';
        var mask = 1 << (i - 1);
        if ((x & mask) != 0) {
            digit++;
        }
        if ((y & mask) != 0) {
            digit++;
            digit++;
        }
        quadKey.push(digit);
    }
    return quadKey.join('');
}
});
```

And this is the exisiting Silverlight code:

```
public override Uri GetUri(int x, int y, int zoomLevel, bool getPrintLink)
    {
        Uri uri = null;
        if (this.Covers(x, y, zoomLevel))
        {
            QuadKey qk = new QuadKey(x, y, zoomLevel);
            if (getPrintLink)
            {
                uri = new Uri(this.CurrentHostURL + "/tiles/NL/" + zoomLevel.ToString() + "/" + qk.Key + ".ipic", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            }
            else
            {
                uri = new Uri("http://tileserver.satmap.com/NL/" + zoomLevel.ToString() + "/" + qk.Key + ".ipic", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            }
        }
        return uri;
    }
```

Any insight would be appreciated as I've trawled many forums and countless pages of search results without finding a solution.

Comment: So you want to use quadkeys to fetch tiles from other sources than Bing, right?

Comment: Basically yes. All of the urls are encoded as per the second example and I've been reading up on creating a custom build of OL3 as I'm unsure whether the latest release has the ol.TileUrlFunction and ol.tilecoord classes baked in.
I don't recognise the tilePoint or Util.template parts of the first example which is completely throwing me.

Comment: @AlvinLindstam, can you possibly help me to understand the ol.TileUrlFunction and how it might apply here? As I understand it, to use a set of tiles for the Netherlands for example, I should define the extent of the tiles as lat, lon, then create a function where I instruct the tile layer source to translate it's XYZ formula to a quad key and pass this as the url. Would I need to convert this back in some way or would it be sufficient to load the tiles correctly?

Comment: See my answer below. That should be enough. Using `EPSG:3857` (default) and the default tile size should probably be the only additional requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, your _quadKey function is correct. The issue that might arise is understanding the [`ol.TileCoord`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.html#.TileCoord) provided to the URL function.

In OpenLayers 3.7 and later, all `TileCoord`s are calculated with the top left corner as their origin. Furthermore, both the X and Y coordinates increase naturally, so that the X and Y coordinates of a TileCoord corresponds to the normal concepts of a two-dimensional axis.

The top left tile of a given zoom level will always have X=0 and Y=-1. The tile below that will have X=0 and Y=-2; Y will always be negative.

Some mapping applications, such as Bing, also use the top left corner as the tile origin, but lets the [Y coordinate increase downwards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx). The top left tile would the be X=0 and Y=0, while the tile below would be X=0 and Y=1.

In order to calculate the quadkeys, the Y coordinate has to be inverted and adjusted by one. [This should work](http://jsfiddle.net/40txm4nx/1/):

```js
// this is unchanged from the question
var quadkey = function (x, y, z) {
    var quadKey = [];
    for (var i = z; i > 0; i--) {
        var digit = '0';
        var mask = 1 << (i - 1);
        if ((x & mask) != 0) {
            digit++;
        }
        if ((y & mask) != 0) {
            digit++;
            digit++;
        }
        quadKey.push(digit);
    }
    return quadKey.join('');
};

var quadKeyLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        maxZoom: 19,
        tileUrlFunction: function (tileCoord, pixelRatio, projection) {
            var z = tileCoord[0];
            var x = tileCoord[1];
            var y = -tileCoord[2] - 1;
            return "//example.com/r" + quadkey(x, y, z);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Many thanks Alvin. I've not quite managed to get it working yet but you've provided a huge step in the right direction. Once it's up and running I will post my solution for anyone else that might come across this issue. Thanks again for taking the time.