# OL3 V3.1.1 to V3.8.2 broke ol.source.xyz from PouchDB

Tags: openlayers-3, pouchdb

I recently updated my Cordova mobile mapping app from OL3 V3.1.1 to V3.7.0 to V3.8.2.

Am using PouchDB to store off-line tiles, and with V3.1.1 tiles were visible.
Here is the code snippet:

```
    OSM_bc_offline_pouchdb = new ol.layer.Tile({
        //maxResolution: 5000,
        //extent: BC,
        //projection: spherical_mercator,
        //crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
        source: new ol.source.XYZ({
            //adapted from: http://jsfiddle.net/gussy/LCNWC/
            tileLoadFunction: function (imageTile, src) {
                pouchTilesDB_osm_bc_baselayer.getAttachment(src, 'tile', function (err, res) {
                    if (err && err.error == 'not_found')
                        return;
                    //if(!res) return;  // ?issue -> causes map refresh on movement to stop 
                    imageTile.getImage().src = window.URL.createObjectURL(res);
                });
            },
            tileUrlFunction: function (coordinate, projection) {
                if (coordinate == null)
                    return undefined;
                // OSM NW origin style URL
                var z = coordinate[0];
                var x = coordinate[1];
                var y = coordinate[2];
                var imgURL = ["tile", z, x, y].join('_');
                return imgURL;
            }
        })
    });
    trails_mobileMap.addLayer(OSM_bc_offline_pouchdb);
    OSM_bc_offline_pouchdb.setVisible(true);
```

Moving to both V3.7.0 and V3.8.2 causes the tiles to not display.  Read the API and I'm missing why this would happen.

What in my code needs updating to work with OL-V3.8.2?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Did you try to join with `/` instead of `_`?

Comment: Why would that make a difference to OL versions?

Comment: Will see about building a test CouchDB with slashes from mbtiles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue might be related to the changes to `ol.TileCoord` in [OpenLayers 3.7.0](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/releases/tag/v3.7.0). From the release notes:

> Until now, the API exposed two different types of ol.TileCoord tile coordinates: internal ones that increase left to right and upward, and transformed ones that may increase downward, as defined by a transform function on the tile grid. With this change, the API now only exposes tile coordinates that increase left to right and upward.
>
> Previously, tile grids created by OpenLayers either had their origin at the top-left or at the bottom-left corner of the extent. To make it easier for application developers to transform tile coordinates to the common XYZ tiling scheme, all tile grids that OpenLayers creates internally have their origin now at the top-left corner of the extent.
>
> This change affects applications that configure a custom tileUrlFunction for an ol.source.Tile. Previously, the tileUrlFunction was called with rather unpredictable tile coordinates, depending on whether a tile coordinate transform took place before calling the tileUrlFunction. Now it is always called with OpenLayers tile coordinates. To transform these into the common XYZ tiling scheme, a custom tileUrlFunction has to change the y value (tile row) of the ol.TileCoord:

```
function tileUrlFunction = function(tileCoord, pixelRatio, projection){
  var urlTemplate = '{z}/{x}/{y}';
  return urlTemplate
      .replace('{z}', tileCoord[0].toString())
      .replace('{x}', tileCoord[1].toString())
      .replace('{y}', (-tileCoord[2] - 1).toString());
}
```

If this is your issue, try changing your `tileUrlFunction` to

```
function (coordinate, projection) {
    if (coordinate == null)
        return undefined;
    // OSM NW origin style URL
    var z = coordinate[0];
    var x = coordinate[1];
    var y = (-coordinate[2] - 1);
    var imgURL = ["tile", z, x, y].join('_');
    return imgURL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This sounds a likely source of my issue, though my data is in osm nw origin. I will check and report back.

Comment: Yes, they both use NW origin but OpenLayers decreases the Y tile coordinate when going downwards, while OSM increases. I wrote more about it in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32614039/5149997

Comment: Fixed the issue in two minutes after days of thrashing about.

Guess I should have read the release notes.

Thanks for providing the background and the fix!