# How to display OSM ZXY with Openlayers 3.7+ Canvas-tile Example

Tags: canvas, openstreetmap, openlayers-3

The Canvas Tiles Openlayers example shows tile grids over an OSM map. The displayed tile coordinates are OpenLayers tile coordinates. These increase from bottom to top, but standard XYZ tiling scheme coordinates increase from top to bottom. The Example page do not document how to show OSM XYZ coordinates.
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/canvas-tiles.html

Post [Using Bing Maps Quadkeys as Openlayers 3 Tile source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32454234/using-bing-maps-quadkeys-as-openlayers-3-tile-source), explains the modfications since OpenLayers 3.7 to TileCoords.

What is missing is how to control the displayed tile coordinates.  Could you descibe how this can be done to display for example 10,512,340 instead of 10,512-341 ?

Comment: Try asking at http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.